# use php to access json without knowing element value

Tags: php, json

JSON looks like this

```
{
    73: {
        id: 74,
        title: "39",
        body: "11100000000000000000#IS#2.5",
        created_at: "2018-04-23 21:19:19",
        updated_at: "2018-04-23 21:19:19"
    }
}
```

I need to access the value of 73 without knowing what 73 is.

```
echo $studentData->;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`reset()`](https://php.net/reset) to get the first member of an object:

```
$json = '{"73":{"id":74,"title":"39","body":"11100000000000000000#IS#2.5","created_at":"2018-04-23 21:19:19", "updated_at":"2018-04-23 21:19:19"}}';

$data = json_decode($json);
$first = reset($data);
var_dump($first);
```

outputs:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["id"] => int(74)
    ["title"] => string(2) "39"
    ["body"] => string(27) "11100000000000000000#IS#2.5"
    ["created_at"] => string(19) "2018-04-23 21:19:19"
    ["updated_at"] => string(19) "2018-04-23 21:19:19"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to decode your json to an array using `json_decode($jsonData, true)` where $jsonData is your json object. This will give you an array and then you can get the 73rd index of that array.

Comment: If he doesn't know that the index is 73, how does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using regular expression

```
$str = '{"73":{"id":74,"title":"39","body":"11100000000000000000#IS#2.5","created_at":"2018-04-23 21:19:19", "updated_at":"2018-04-23 21:19:19"}}';

preg_match('/{.*?({.*?}).*?}/s', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

$result = json_decode($matches[1][0]);

var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
public 'id' => int 74
public 'title' => string '39' (length=2)
public 'body' => string '11100000000000000000#IS#2.5' (length=27)
public 'created_at' => string '2018-04-23 21:19:19' (length=19)
public 'updated_at' => string '2018-04-23 21:19:19' (length=19)
```